# I need a help. Kindly find the below code

Tags: wix

I have created two dialogs. Once clicked CustomCheckA (Nextbutton) it should go to CustomCheckB dialog and once clicked yes on the CustomCheckB dialog it should move to next new dialog. and it should hide the previous dialog. What need to be added in the below code to hide the CustomCheckA dialog

```
<Dialog Id='CustomCheckA' X='50' Y='50' Width='373' Height='287' Title='[ProductName]'>          
<Control Id='Next' Type='PushButton' X='300' Y='261' Width='66' Height='18' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&amp;Next &gt;' TabSkip='no' Default='yes' >       
            <Publish Event='SpawnDialog' Value='CustomCheckB' />
<Dialog>  
<Dialog Id='CustomCheckB' X='50' Y='50' Width='373' Height='100' Title='[ProductName]'>
                <Control Id='NoButton' Type='PushButton' X='300' Y='60' Width='65' Height='21' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&amp;No' TabSkip='no' Default='yes' Cancel='yes'>
                    <Publish Event='EndDialog' Value='Exit' />
                </Control>
                <Control Id='YesButton' Type='PushButton' X='230' Y='60' Width='65' Height='21' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&amp;Yes' TabSkip='no' Default='yes' >               
                <Publish Event='NewDialog' Value='[CustomCheckB_NextArgs]'><![CDATA[CustomCheckB_NextArgs<>""]]></Publish>
          </Control>
                <Control Id='BodyText' Type='Text' X='6' Y='9' Width='345' Height='36' Text='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}WARNING' TabSkip='yes' NoPrefix='yes' />
            </Dialog>
```

Comment: Hi, the code you are referencing to is missing.

Comment: Selected code in editor, pressed Ctrl+K, pressed Save.